# Hide text from frame but include in handout using beamer

Tags: beamer

I have a latex file I use for teaching which I compile in two ways, either as a handout or as slides using beamer (i.e. two wrappers for a single file).

I know that I can include extra text in the handout by ensuring it is not inside the frame environment:

```
Some text for the handout bla bla
\frame{ Some text and figures for both the slide and handout bla bla}
Some more text for the handout etc...
```

But sometimes I want to include text in the handout that may fit nicely in the text-flow mid-slide so to speak, so I was wondering if there was a way to make the "frame" environment ignore chunks of text mid-frame?

i.e. something along the lines of

```
\frame{Figure XXX shows this and that etc etc
[SOME EXTRA TEXT IN THE HANDOUT I WANT TO LEAVE OFF THE SLIDE]
figure here}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass[%
   handout
]{beamer}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

Figure XXX shows this and that etc etc

\only<handout>{SOME EXTRA TEXT IN THE HANDOUT I WANT TO LEAVE OFF THE SLIDE}

figure here

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```